# While Mocking JDBCTemplate , getting No DataSource Specified Error

Tags: mocking, mockito

I am writing TestCase for the following method

```
@Repository
public class CustomerContactDaoImpl implements CustomerContactDao {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "dcv_jdbc_template")
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    @Override
    public void insertCustomer(Contact contact) {
        SimpleJdbcCall call = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withProcedureName("ins_customerinfo");
                try {
            call.execute(new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("customerid", contact.getCustomerID())));
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

And this is my Test Case

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class CustomerContactDaoImplTest {
    @InjectMocks
    CustomerContactDaoImpl customerContactDaoImpl;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

      @Test
       public void insertCustomerContactTest() throws Exception {
        Contact contact = Mockito.mock(Contact.class);
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateMock = Mockito.mock(JdbcTemplate.class);
        SimpleJdbcCall mockedSimpleJdbcCall = Mockito.mock(SimpleJdbcCall.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(SimpleJdbcCall.class).withArguments(jdbcTemplateMock).thenReturn(mockedSimpleJdbcCall);
        mockedSimpleJdbcCall.execute(new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("customerid", contact.getCustomerID())));
       customerContactDaoImpl.insertCustomerContact(contact);
}

}
```

I am getting Error as

**While Mocking   JDBCTemplate , getting No DataSource Specified Error**

Please let me know how to resolve this error

```
org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.TooManyConstructorsFoundException: Several matching constructors found, please specify the argument parameter types so that PowerMock can determine which method you're referring to.
Matching constructors in class org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall were:
org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall( javax.sql.DataSource.class )
org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall( org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.class )

    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.throwExceptionWhenMultipleConstructorMatchesFound(WhiteboxImpl.java:1723)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.findUniqueConstructorOrThrowException(WhiteboxImpl.java:1097)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.DefaultConstructorExpectationSetup.createNewSubstituteMock(DefaultConstructorExpectationSetup.java:94)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.DefaultConstructorExpectationSetup.withArguments(DefaultConstructorExpectationSetup.java:54)
    at com.nrg.bccd.dao.test.CustomerContactDaoImplTest.insertCustomerContactTest(CustomerContactDaoImplTest.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:88)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:96)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
```

Comment: Such a test is completely useless anyway. Assuming it worked, what would it tell you about your code? Would it make sure that the insert would actually work fine when actually executed? That's what the test should ensure.

Comment: ok Thanks for the input , any suggestions on how to approach it ?

Comment: Execute the actual code, without mocking anything, and check if the data that is supposed to be inserted in the database is indeed inserted in the database.

Comment: but dont u think so that Database will be corrupted with unnecessary data , if i do the real inserts

Comment: Tests don't run in production. They run in the development or the CI environment. And you can use a different database or schema than the one you use for your manual tests.

Comment: Ok , In our Case the dev and Stg databases are same , so can't go for the approach you suggested

Comment: You means that all developers on the team share the exact same database and schema? How can you even make a change in the database schema without making it impossible for everyone else to keep working? You need to change that.

Comment: Did you tried my answer? can you give feedback?

Answer (score 4):

Tight coupling makes testing this code difficult in isolation without unexpected behavior.

But lets address the test in its current state.

`@InjectMocks` is used,

```java
@InjectMocks
CustomerContactDaoImpl customerContactDaoImpl;
```

yet a manual mock is declared within the test

```java
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateMock = Mockito.mock(JdbcTemplate.class);
```

and used as argument matcher

```java
PowerMockito.whenNew(SimpleJdbcCall.class).withArguments(jdbcTemplateMock).thenReturn(mockedSimpleJdbcCall);
```

Since the instance used when setting up the `new SimpleJdbcCall(...` is not the one injected when the test is exercised then the arguments wont match and an actual instance of `SimpleJdbcCall` will be created, and it will try to use a mocked `JdbcTemplate`(Not the one you mocked) and bam, error.

The test needs to be refactored in order to verify the expected behavior when exercised.

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(CustomerContactDaoImpl.class) //prepare the class creating the new instance
public class CustomerContactDaoImplTest {

    @Mock
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateMock; //YOUR MOCK TO BE INJECTED

    @InjectMocks
    CustomerContactDaoImpl customerContactDaoImpl;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void insertCustomerContactTest() throws Exception {
        //Arrange
        string paramName = "customerid";
        string expected = "fakeCustomerIdHere"; //assumption made as to type;
        Contact contact = Mockito.mock(Contact.class);
        when(contact.getCustomerID()).thenReturn(expected);

        SimpleJdbcCall mockedSimpleJdbcCall = Mockito.mock(SimpleJdbcCall.class);
        when(mockedSimpleJdbcCall.withProcedureName(anyString()))
            .thenReturn(mockedSimpleJdbcCall);

        PowerMockito.whenNew(SimpleJdbcCall.class).withArguments(jdbcTemplateMock)
            .thenReturn(mockedSimpleJdbcCall);

        //Act
        customerContactDaoImpl.insertCustomerContact(contact);

        //Assert
        verify(mockedSimpleJdbcCall).execute(any(MapSqlParameterSource.class));
        verify(contact).getCustomerID();
    }
}
```

Comment: hi , i am using mockito 1.8 version , and the verify call is not working , getting NullPointerException at             call.execute(new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("customerid", contact.getCustomerID())));
 as call is null

Comment: It is working , but in the code coverage , the execution part is 0 for the method

Comment: @user974802 That is because most of the body of that method under test consists of mocks when exercised in the test. And the reason for that is because of the tight coupling to implementation details. Which meant you had to use powermock.

Comment: @user974802 but at least you can confirm that the test works

Comment: The test works , but how can the code coverage would be solved ? any guess

Comment: @user974802 the way the current code is designed it would only get covered with an integration test that uses actual implementations. The fact that powermock had to be used is a false positive. `SimpleJdbcCall` should actually have been explicitly injected or at least passed via some factory abstraction.

Comment: @user974802 code coverage in this case is also a false indicator.

Answer (score 1):

Follow [Spring JDBC tests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jdbc/src/test/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcCallTests.java), first mock all database objects:

> ```
> @BeforeEach
> public void setUp() throws Exception {
>     connection = mock(Connection.class);
>     databaseMetaData = mock(DatabaseMetaData.class);
>     dataSource = mock(DataSource.class);
>     callableStatement = mock(CallableStatement.class);
>     given(connection.getMetaData()).willReturn(databaseMetaData);
>     given(dataSource.getConnection()).willReturn(connection);
> }
> ```

And use them in test:

> ```
> @Test
> public void testAddInvoiceProcWithoutMetaDataUsingMapParamSource() throws Exception {
>     initializeAddInvoiceWithoutMetaData(false);
>     SimpleJdbcCall adder = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource).withProcedureName("add_invoice");
>     adder.declareParameters(
>             new SqlParameter("amount", Types.INTEGER),
>             new SqlParameter("custid", Types.INTEGER),
>             new SqlOutParameter("newid", Types.INTEGER));
>     Number newId = adder.executeObject(Number.class, new MapSqlParameterSource().
>             addValue("amount", 1103).
>             addValue("custid", 3));
>     assertThat(newId.intValue()).isEqualTo(4);
> ```